# Can we break RSA with an optical Fourier transform?

Tags: rsa, quantum-cryptography

We all know that RSA can be compromised using Shor's quantum algorithm. The horsepower underlying this algorithm is the [Fourier transform](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/schwartz/files/lecture8-fouriertransforms.pdf). However, we can use alternatives to perform this function, such as [an optical Fourier transform coprocessor with direct phase determination](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-13733-1).

According to the paper, you may need a high-resolution optical sensor for this task. But how high does it need to be? Can we get a rough estimation using a lower resolution and guess something close?

Are such alternatives viable (in the near future) to break RSA?

PS: The largest optical sensor in existence is a [3.2 gigapixel](https://petapixel.com/2019/09/27/this-is-the-worlds-largest-optical-lens-its-5-feet-wide-and-took-5-years-to-make/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The horsepower underlying this algorithm is the Fourier transform

Not quite; the algorithm is to generate a superposition of states, compute the modular exponentiation of those states (generating the superposition of those results), and then use a Quantum FFT (actually, the inverse FFT[1]) to find a periodicity (and from such a period, you can deduce the factorization).

The issue for you is that this is an inherently quantum operation; the hardware you linked to performs a Discrete (Classical) FFT [2], which doesn't operation on superpositions.  And, if you don't perform the inverse FFT on a superposition, then you can't implement Shor's algorithm.

Hence, your idea using an optical hardware within superposition doesn't solve the problem at all...

> Are such alternatives viable (in a near future) to break RSA?

It doesn't appear that way...

[1] Requiring an inverse FFT isn't the main objection - I believe optics can perform that operation as well...

[2] Actually, it's rather easy to compute FFTs (and inverse FFTs) in software - the linked hardware's just claims it can compute it somewhat faster, but software already is pretty fast...

Comment: OK, seems we can still rest for awhile.

Comment: @shumy: yes, at least until someone builds a moderately large error-correcting Quantum Computer...

Answer (score 0):

The sequence you would need to Fourier transform is of the order of $2^n$ for an $n$-bit RSA key, $n= 2048$  is usual. That's far too big for any classical machine, even using physical optics.

Comment: Welcome to cryptography.se. We have $\LaTeX$/MathJax installed for ourside.